# How to include edges in Gremlin while doing breadth first search?

Tags: groovy, gremlin, bulbs, rexster

In my gremlin query, I have the following:

```
vert.as('x').
both.or(
  _().has("time").filter{ it.time.toInteger() > startTime.toInteger() },
  _().has("isRead"), _().has("isWrite")).dedup().gather.scatter.
store(y).loop('x'){c++ < limit.toInteger()}.iterate();
```

In my gremlin script, I return y, but y clearly only has vertices in it. I can manually retrieve each of the edges manually by iterating over them for each of the vertices, but I want a list returned that contains only the edges between other nodes returned in the list y.

In particular, I need to be able to recreate the sub-graph returned within a data structure locally, so gremlin is being used to return that information. Other details about my use case that influence these needs are the fact that manually iterating over each of the nodes edges is too slow, since the rexster server I'm running my bulbs script against has to push the data over the wire, and also because if I don't have the set of edges between each of the vertices that were originally returned using the script, then I have to check each vertice encountered along each edge to make sure that it's within the set originally returned; very non-ideal.

Basically, any result should be such that, when I look at any of the returned vertices I can know what vertices are linked within the returned set--without having to do any manual checking or lookups. It should merely be in the dataset.

**EDIT 1:**

I found that gremlin's tree pipeline capability was really good for doing exactly what I wanted! The problem is, now that I use tree, I need to return it to a form that can be used... I can only return either vertexes or edges, so I can't return tree straight away.

**EDIT 2:**

espeed is right; I should use bothE to start with. But I have some conditions that I want to satisfy... I almost had it earlier, but I couldn't get the filter to work correctly.

```
vert.as('l').
bothE.gather.scatter.as('edge').bothV.or(
  _().has("time").filter{ it.getProperty('time').toInteger() >= startTime.toInteger() },
  _().has("isRead"), _().has("isWrite")).
dedup().store(results).as('vertice').back('edge').store(results).back('vertice')
.loop('l'){c++ < limit.toInteger()}.iterate();
```

I don't understand why I can't use two backs in one pipeline (I get a NullPointerException with this one). The basic problem I want solved is: do a breadth first search, storing only the nodes that satisfy all of the or above, and store the edges between all vertices that pass the test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without messing with your code too much, maybe the easiest thing is to do:

```
results = [] as Set
vert.as('l').
bothE.as('e').gather.scatter.as('edge').bothV.or(
  _().has("time").filter{ it.getProperty('time').toInteger() >= startTime.toInteger()}.store(results),
  _().has("isRead"), _().has("isWrite")).store(results))
.sideEffect{e,m->results<<m.e}
.loop('l'){c++ < limit.toInteger()}.iterate();
```

Note that declaring results as `Set` you can avoid the `dedup` step.  Basically store the vertices as you filter them in the `or` step.

Comment: Well that's pretty close to what I wanted to do, and I think I've done something almost like that while editing the code over and over; the problem with this is, when you do back('edge') it then forwards the result from edge to store, but store just passes it on too. When loop gets the current element value, it's an edge, and at as('l'), it's expected to be a vertice in order for bothE to resolve. That's why I had to "back" pieces up there, but it always threw NullPointerException...

Comment: Moving as('l') around doesn't solve it though; I think the only thing that needs to happen is the vertice that's being stored at has("isWrite")).store(results) needs to be the vertice that gets sent back to as('l')...

Comment: i got rid of the back and just "cheated' by naming the edge step and referencing it from a `sideEffect`...does that work? just trying to get you to an answer so you can iterate from there...maybe this isn't the best approach.

Comment: This look correct, and thanks so so much, I had no idea how to do that, I had even looked into it, but I'm unfamiliar with Groovy.  Although it looks correct, when I run it, even though I increase limit, it doesn't seem to add more results... I'll check back and find out why, it may be my data...

Comment: You can read about step closures here....good stuff: https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin/wiki/Step-Closures

Comment: I've read it and stuff (it's just difficult to debug groovy since I have nothing other than rexster to run against and python bulbs to throw scripts at it, no debugging in other words), I found that although you selected set, without the dedup step, it would loop cyclically around vertices it had seen before (maybe just how we wrote it). I added a dedup step and it fixed it. The as Set helps anyway though, because that I want. :) Thanks so much! You fixed it for me!

Comment: Use the Gremlin REPL to edit/debug Gremlin scripts (Rexster isn't meant for that). Ideally you'd create/test a Gremlin script just like you'd test a Python script -- create a Gremlin-Groovy file for your code and run Groovy tests -- this flow is much easier. Then once your Gremlin script is working, add it to Bulbs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bothE()` instead of `both()` to access to the edges...

See http://gremlindocs.com/#transform/bothe

Comment: Thank you once again espeed.